# Unable to query between three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have trying to query two tables and show some result but no luck so far.
This is the sql query which I try

```
SELECT * FROM tables  
     JOIN reservation ON reservation.selected = m.table_id
     WHERE table_rest = '$rest_id'
     AND reservation.status is NULL
```

The idea is to show all tables. Those tables with `status` will be not show. Currently this work with three tables i.e. one middle but I don't want to have middle table. That's why I trying. This is current query which is working

```
SELECT m.*
        FROM tables m
        JOIN table_rest mr ON m.table_id = mr.table_id
        LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.selected = m.table_id
        WHERE rest_id = '$rest_id'
        AND reservation.status is NULL
```

Update:
This is current structure
[image]
I want to remove `table_rest` table. I have `table_rest` column in `tables` which hold `restaurant_id`. I hope is a bit clear now?

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: The working query has a `LEFT JOIN`, where the other one has an `[INNER] JOIN`, also I think there is a difference between `table_rest` and `rest_id`, although it's not really clear to which tables they belong. Your naming seems to be not very consistent.

Comment: Just a sec.. I will show what exactly I trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, I think, your matched column in `tables` and `reservation` is table_id so add join on that column

```
SELECT m.table_id, table_name, table_image, table_image_big, table_description 
FROM tables m 
LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.selectedTable = m.table_id 
WHERE table_rest = '$restaurant_id' 
AND reservation.status is NULL";
```

Comment: I have removed second table in `JOIN table_rest` and added in first table `tables` column `table_rest` that's why i put `table_rest` in where clause

Comment: I will draw it .. just a sec

Comment: modified answer... matched column in tables and reservation is table_id? right

Comment: in tables is `table_rest` and in reservation is table_id

Comment: can you add sample data for tables and reservation , and expected output...right now its bit confused which column has which value?

Comment: I will try. Just a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68606/discussion-between-piyush-and-goro).